# XML, TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, parsing, flex4

Can anyone see whats wrong with either the code to grab the XML or the XML file itself? It looks well formed to me and I don't see the cause of the error:

**A TypeError has occured: 
    TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.**

```
    var file:String = 'config.xml';
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);
    loader.load(request);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", onComplete);
    loader.addEventListener("ioError", onIOError);

    private function onIOError(event:Event):void 
    {
        trace("IOERROR (maybe XML file does not exit or have an incorrect name)");
    }

    private function onComplete(event:Event):void 
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
        if (loader != null) {
            try {
                var settings:XML = new XML(loader.data);
            } catch (e:TypeError) {
                trace("A TypeError has occured: \r\t" + e);
            }

        } else {
            trace("Loader is not a URLLoader!");
        }
    }
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <setting1>1</setting1>
    <showDebug>2</showDebug>
    <someOtherSetting>3</someOtherSetting>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you create the XML document in?

I had something similar occur the other day, depending on the text/xml editor it may add a Byte Order Mark to the beginning [Wikipedia BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) . This instantly invalidates the XML file. Try copying and pasting what you have into notepad and re-saving it.

Or, if you have a Linux machine available, the BOM will appear in VI as '' and you can remove it.

Also, just for reference, the utf encoding for the BOM is '\ufeff'

Comment: Window's Notepad... I've also been editing directly in Eclipse. Ill try what you suggest

Comment: Even though I thought I tried this previously, creating a new file with the same info in vim did the trick. Thanks!